# Django ORM many to many filter by authors and the count of books

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I'm using Django 2.2

I have two tables with the Many-to-Many relation

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I have a list of authors `first_name`

```
author_names = ['john', 'parker', 'donald']
```

**How can I get the count of books each author have?**

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Author.objects.values('first_name').annotate(count_books=Count('book'))
```

which will return a queryset that is grouped by `Author`'s first_name. In the result of this queryset you can also see the number of books based on each `Author`'s first_name (like `<QuerySet [{'first_name': 'john', 'count_books': 1}, {'first_name': 'parker', 'count_books': 3}]>`) and if you want to filter this queryset you can change it to:

```
Author.objects.filter(first_name__in=author_names).values('first_name').annotate(count_books=Count('book'))
```

However if you want to see how many books is related to each `Author` object you can do something like:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Author.objects.values('id').annotate(count_books=Count('book'))
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan. What if one book has two authors. Will it count that book for both the authors?

Comment: You're welcome and the answer is yes, it'll count it per each user even if a book has more than one author.

Comment: how can we use Count('book') if there is no 'book' column Author table